# Android PictureCallback needs to execute first then continue to other code

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I have code to take a picture that works, but after it gets to `PictureCallback()`, it continues chugging on code-wise and I end up executing other code before I have my byte array. Is there any way to halt this? It only takes milliseconds and I don't think I would mind halting the UI thread.

```
private static byte[] patronImage;
.
.
.
takePatronPicture();
//I want to do something with patronImage here, but the next line
//gets executed almost immediately while getJpegCallback is still
//doing its thing.
code that does something with patronImage;
.
.
.
public void takePatronPicture(){
        if (camera != null) {
            try {
              SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView)getView().findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
              camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder());    
              camera.startPreview(); 
              camera.takePicture(null, null, getJpegCallback);  
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }          
        }
    }

    final PictureCallback getJpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            try {  
                patronImage = data;

                camera.release();
                camera = null;
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a callback is that it will call you later when its done.  If you have additional code to run that requires the operation's data, you put it in the callback.  You don't freeze your current thread waiting for it.  In fact doing so may lead to deadlock if the operation posts an event to the main thread's looper.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I can't see the forrest for the trees.